# How to query nested object of a model in backbone using .where()

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections, backbone-model

I have collection name @collection. Each model of @collection looks like this:

```
{
name : "example",
layout : {
    x : 100,
    y : 100,
  }
}
```

I have to do find models where 
`model.attributes.layout[x] == '100'`.

Can I do something like this `@collection.where({layout[x] :100})` ? Or are there other ways to do such kind of query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) method

`collection.filter(function(model) { return model.get('layout).x === 100; })`